# Twtitter Bootstrap installation issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

First off, I'd like to say that I have searched high and low, read multiple tutorials and a couple posts on this site about this and it has not helped, so I've decided to make my own post.

I'm trying to self-teach web development / server administration using Twitter Bootstrap, as I already have some background in HTML and CSS. I've installed my LAMP stack and all my dependencies correctly as far as I'm aware.

My file structure looks like this:

- /var/www/
- /var/www/icyou/
- /var/www/icyou/bootstrap

  -all of the files created when checking out bootstrap, left untouched-
- /var/www/icyou/site_root/

  index.html

  index.html.save

  testphp.php

Inside of my index.html is the Twitter Bootstrap's default template, which is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>

    <a href="#" class="btn"> It works</a>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The only thing I changed in the index.html that isn't identical to the template is the `<a href="#" class="btn"> It works</a>`.

I am following a tutorial set on youtube that shows that the button should have at a mouse-over effect as well as the text being in the popular bootstrap sans-sarif font. Mine looks like raw HTML.

I'm hoping it's something as simple as a dependency issue I'm unaware of. It's really very frustrating, installing all these packages. It seems that everyone aside from me has an innate knowledge of dependency scoping so nobody ever mentions it.

---

Edit: I have also tried changing the paths to complete paths for the time being:

```
<link href="/var/www/icyou/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="/var/www/icyou/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your file structure doesn't match your path for the bootstrap CSS file. You need the bootstrap css file to be in a folder named CSS that is a sub-folder of the location where you have index.html.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the permissions on the folder /var/www/icyou/site_root/ ?
Also you might want to open up the "inspect element" dialog (if you're in chrome) it will surely say what's going on with your css links

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding question correctly, you are not seeing the 'hover' effect when you mouse-over the button?

Bootstrap handles multiple classes on a single element so for example if I was to implement a button I would do something like:

Btn-primary assign the color to the button
  Btn-md assigns the size of the button. 
  Using simply 'btn' is going to give you the bare minimum.

Try adding a few additional class attributes to the button and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! Both answers were really helpful, but the comment was closer to what I was having issue with. It's what I thought and a relative path issue. My bootstrap folder was in the directory above my apache document root, and apparently you cannot have a path that goes beyond the scope of the document root!

New path looks like this `<link href="/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`