# how to install bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

using a windows 7 and just a few days back i downloaded the bootstrap 3.3.1 dist file..... but i don't know how to install it.... i also don't know what to put for my href="???" in the link .... 
this code is a mixture of my own writing and some copy/paste of the scripts from the bootstrap site... i'm totally messed up...someone please help......

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Edwin's School of Music</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="../../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Bootstrap theme -->
<link href="../../dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>C:\Users\user\Desktop\bootstrap-3.3.1-dist\dist\css\bootstrap.min.css
<body>
    <div class="nav">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="pull-left">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Materials</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="pull-right">
                <li><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h2>Welcome to...</h2>
        <h1><strong>Edwin's School Of Music</strong></h1>
        <h2>Make your DREAMS come true ...</h2>
    </div>
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../assets/js/docs.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Your path for the files may be wrong. Add your folder structure to the question. [Also this may give you an idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22491871/twtitter-bootstrap-installation-issues?rq=1)

Comment: Why do people say 'install bootstrap' ?

Comment: i'm sorry @anpsmn but i don't exactly know how to get that i.e. the folder structure

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal i'm new to bootstrap.... and since i had to download the dist file i assumed that an installation should follow... thats why ...

Comment: You just have to download the files and put them on your server and finally link to them in your code

Comment: how do i link them after downloading??

Comment: @EdwinCharles I meant you can check in your PC where the files are.  You have to check where your index.html(the page with the above code) is placed and where the bootstrap.css is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

This will work & no need to install things

However, this will only work if you have an internet connection as they are being fetched from a server, rather than a local file on your machine.

Comment: so there is no particular need to download the dist file??

Comment: @Edwin Charles No, no need to do that if you put this code in your html

Comment: alright i tried it and worked perfectly ... thank you .... But how can u access the bootstrap in your system???

Comment: I am afraid you are not possible to do that: using this code you link an external script to your code.

Comment: If you want to use customised bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/customize/
then I am afraid you need to download the files and put them on your server

Comment: Do you want to use normal or customized bootstrap?

Comment: what are the benefits of customized over normal??

Comment: Customized definitely takes more time/work but you can change bootstrap to your preferences (e.g. make the navbar another color than the default one)

Comment: ok then i guess i'll stick on to normal.... THANKS a lot .... you've been very helpful cause i've been trying so hard for a few days....

Comment: No problem. Can you close this question by approving an anwser?